# WordPress search not submitting

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the following code for a search bar. When you click the submit, it does nothing. It is not even directing to another page. I am using the Understrap theme.

```
<div id="search">
                        <form action="/" method="get">
                            <input type="search" placeholder="Type your search word(s) here" value="<?php get_search_query(); ?>" />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `action` attribute your site url instead of `'/'`. Sometime '/' want be useful.

```
<div id="search">

    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">

    <input type="search" placeholder="Type your search word(s) here" value="<?php get_search_query(); ?>" />
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
       </form>
    </div>
```